# Thoughtspot: API calls to fetch metadata via Python

Tags: python, postman

I'm trying to fetch metadata from thoughtspot. I am able to call the url using browser and fetch the data. But here I'm trying to achieve it via python program. According to thougthspot documentation. I have to enable trusted authentication and pass my secret key & username to obtain a token which I can use in my program.

https://developers.thoughtspot.com/docs/?pageid=api-auth-session

```
my username : username@username.com
secret key : secret-key
```

Below is my code:(generated by postman)

```
import requests

url = "https://<ThoughtSpot-host>/callosum/v1/tspublic/v1/session/auth/token?auth_token=secret-key&access_level=FULL&username=username@username.com"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I'm getting Bad request error. Anyone here using thoughtspot over this issue. Appreciate your support very much.

Error I'm getting:

```
{"type":"Bad Request","description":"The server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax."}
```

I can fetch data by calling the api using a web-browser. Below url returns list of all meta-data objects. I want to achieve this using a python program (I have to authenticate first & call the below URL - Authentication step is not working for me when I tried to follow the documentation)

```
https://<ThoughtSpot-host>/callosum/v1/tspublic/v1/metadata/list
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the url so that it includes the domain name?
Also post the error you are getting. And a screenshot of a working request would be great!

Comment: Yes, I changed the URL. I'm able to fetch the metadata manually through browser, its the authentication step which is throwing the error I have added the error message and updated the question

Comment: If you don't share the url with us, we cannot help you